# A query regarding SHA256 output hash structure vs input entropy?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis

Given an Input string of N bytes where some bytes positions in the string are fixed/immutable (F Bytes) and rest of the bytes positions can contain any value as we want or are configurable/variable (V = N-F Bytes).

SHA256(SHA256(N)) = H (256 bits).

Now, Given an Input string of N bytes, the values of N, F, V and the positions which can change and which can't:

How do we calculate the probability/formula that for at least 1 assignment of values in V, the calculated H has k leading bytes as 0?

For eg: For a random input string of size N, N=80, F=40, V=40 (assuming the position information is also given) how do we know/calculate the probability that for at least 1 assignment of values in V first k bytes of H are 0?

I tried searching for some analysis on this but couldn't find any answer. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, the location of the fixed byte or the number of them doesn't matter if we assume that the output is randomized.

Let's assume bits, so $v = 8 \cdot V$.

Now for one value, the chance of it starting with $k$ bits can be brought down to the chance that the first $k$ bits have a constant value. The size of the hash does not matter. So for one try this is just $1 \over 2^k$.

As the output is randomized, we can also conclude that the outputs are not related; each try has the same chance. In that case it is much like rolling dice, so the computation is similar to one minus the chance of *not* throwing a 6 in an amount of throws.

So that means that the probability is one minus the chance that the constant value of $k$ bits is not thrown:

$$1 - \bigg({{2^k-1} \over {2^k}}\bigg)^{2^v} = 1 - (1 - 2^{-k})^{2^v}$$

Now this seems daunting, but you can play around with (small) values [using WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=1-+Power%5B%5C%2840%29++Divide%5BPower%5B2%2Ck%5D-1%2CPower%5B2%2Ck%5D%5D+%5C%2841%29%2CPower%5B2%2Cv%5D%5D%5C%2844%29+v%3D10%5C%2844%29+k%3D12).

Note that if $v$ is becomes larger than $k$ then the probability quickly goes towards 1, while it quickly moves to zero when $k$ becomes larger than $v$ - which makes sense, they are used as exponents after all.

As we assume that SHA-256 already randomizes the output, this seems to have nothing to do with entropy at all, a counter with size $v$ would work just as well as random input - better even since there is no chance of duplicates.

Comment: Note that WolframAlpha tries to calculate the exact amount; if somebody has a nice approximation (e.g. in $\log_2$ form) then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

*Really a comment but more room here for displaymath:*

Regarding @MaartenBodewes request for a closed form expression, we can proceed as follows. Since $$(1-2^{-k})^{2^k}\rightarrow \exp(-1)$$ for even moderately large  $k$ we can write
$$(1-2^{-k})^{2^v}=[ (1-2^{-k})^{2^k} ]^{2^{v-k}}=\exp(-2^{v-k})
$$
so the required expression is
$$
1-\exp(-2^{v-k})
$$
which is extremely sensitive to the difference between $k$ and $v$.

Also, I think the remark about this question having nothing to do with input entropy is a bit too strong. This expression is independent of the input entropy since it essentially uses the random oracle model for the hash function. For a specific hash such as SHA, the entropy would matter but modelling it would be devilishly difficult, I think